# Why does the C(++) preprocessor allow be to define a macro but not check if it's not defined?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, ifndef

If I have a simple statement like this:

```
#ifndef A(B)
#define A(B) B
#endif
```

I get a compilation error...

```
error: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive [-Werror]
 #ifndef A(B)
          ^
```

But if I write (say):

```
#ifndef A
#define A(B) B
#endif
```

I have no problem - why is it possible to define this macro but it's not possible to check if it's not defined? That seems somewhat odd.

Comment: "why is it possible to define this macro but it's not possible to check if it's not defined?" But as you demonstrate, `#ifndef A` checks is `A` is defined.  Since you're asking the question I assume you're trying to ask a different question; is it, "how do you detect that a macro is a function like macro" perchance?

Comment: Clearly the token A is not the same as the token A(B) - so I'm not sure what your point is? I was merely demonstrating that the #ifndef/#define/#endif structure worked in general.

Comment: `A(B)` isn't a token; it's four tokens.  `#define A(B) B` defines a macro called `A`, which is function-like with a single parameter `B`, and a replacement list `B`.  There can only be one macro called `A` at any given time, be it object-like, or function-like with any number of parameters.  `#ifdef A` checks if a macro called `A` is defined.  Is your question why `#ifdef A(B)` doesn't work then?